# UnobtrusiveValidationMode set to WebForms forces Postback?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using WebForms Web Application (not MVC).

Is there any reason why when I have this appSetting set to "WebForms" that it forces a postback for validation instead of catching the missing required fields on the client side?

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

The validation works fine.  The Page.IsValid catches that it's not a valid form submit and the RequiredFieldValidators fire off just fine after the postback but it just doesn't catch it on the client side unless I change the setting to "None".

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```